# Can you tell me how to use KITTI Dataset?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't find any rosbag or pcap dataset for velodyne in KITTI's website.I just found png dataset for a paper of Velodyne SLAM.Can you tell me where the dataset you have used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261599/can-you-tell-me-how-to-use-kitti-dataset?/) by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on 2017-05-12**:
add:Or how can i use the png dataset(https://www.mrt.kit.edu/z/publ/download/velodyneslam/dataset.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the [kitti-player](https://github.com/iralabdisco/kitti_player) package can help you. There have been several questions asked regarding this topic, so there might be some additional info in these questions as well.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [kitti2bag](https://github.com/tomas789/kitti2bag) to convert KITTI dataset to rosbag, which currently support raw data and odometry data (for grayscale and rgb image), however it's still did not support velodyne dataset for odometry dataset. you can use raw dataset instead since it have a mapping between raw and odometry dataset.

hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [nobinov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30226/nobinov/) with karma: 66 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1